# Substitution method integral notation

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int u^n \frac{du}{dx} dx = \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$
The above equation is equal to the simpler integral
$$\int u^n du =  \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

which suggests that the simpler expression $du$ can be substituted for $(du/dx)dx$ when
computing an integral. Leibniz, one of the founders of calculus, had the insight that indeed
this substitution could be done, leading to the substitution method for computing integrals.
As with differentials, when computing integrals we have
$$\color{magenta}{du} = \color{red}{\frac{du}{dx}} \color{orange}{dx}$$

---

This is from my book. My question is on the last part. Does the orange and magenta means the differentials while the red is just the derivative operator (and not the quotient of differentials) applied on function $u$? I also know that differential $du$ is defined to be $u'(x)dx$.

Comment: $\frac{du}{dx}$ is just the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$. Since as you say one defines $du = u'(x)dx$ for a variable $dx$ then by cancellation $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u'(x)dx}{dx}=u'(x)$. So you can think of it either as the derivative operator or as a quotient of differentials, as this definition makes the two equivalent.

Comment: @Dan - before you can do that calculation, you have to define what it means to divide differentials, and of course before you can do that, you have to define what a differential actually is. It is evident, I think, that Sayanada is still at the stage where textbooks simply ignore these inconvenient facts, and pretend that differentials just exist, without addressing what they actually are.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Actually the textbook clearly defines what differentials are: "Let $y=f(x)$ be a differentiable function. The differential $dx$ is an independent variable. The differential $dy$ is $dy=f'(x)dx$". The book also states that the differential $dx$ in the integral basically means that we're integrating with respect to $x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  It also states the origin as follows: "Leibniz introduced a notation for the definite integral that captures its construction as
a limit of Riemann sums. He envisioned the finite sums $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k)\triangle x_k$ ($c_k$ is any number chosen in the $k$th subinterval) becoming an infinite sum of function values $f(x)$ multiplied by “infinitesimal” subinterval widths $dx$."

Comment: @Sayanada - I give your book kudos for being a little more sophisticated in describing differentials than most at this level. But please be aware that this is a much, much deeper subject than has been shown to you. However, that quote about origins would make even Mel Gibson and Oliver Stone blush from the historical inaccuracy. Riemann came much later than Leibnitz, who was not envisioning finite sums, and most definitely did not put quotes around "infinitesimal".

Comment: Liebnitz's concept of differentials was that they were actual *infinitely small* values. It was a view of differentials later mockingly described by Berkeley as being "the ghosts of departed quantities". The Riemann sum came roughly 2 centuries after Liebnitz, when mathematicians were trying to put solid foundations under the house of cards their predecessors had built. (And FYI - a foundation was eventually built for the Liebnitzian view in the 1960s called "Non-Standard Analysis" - though there is a part of it I find too hand-wavy for my tastes.)